# Pie Filling temperature

Tags: pie, filling

I made a large batch of strawberry rhubarb pie filling and apple pie filling.  How long can it sit out on the counter and at what temperature has it spoiled?

Answer (score 0):

The general rule for foods is that they shouldn't spend more than two hours in the 'danger zone' which is between 5 and 60 degrees Celsius. So once your pie fillings have cooled below 60 degrees they shouldn't be out for more than two hours, according to the strictest rules of food safety.

That said, a pie filling is typically rather similar to a jam which is a way to preserve fruits and berries. They typically contain to much sugar to spoil, so the main risk is mold if left out of the fridge for weeks. Whether your pie filling would have that property depends on the recipe you use.